# SwiftUI | Implementing FocusState on TextField embedded in UIKit's navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm in the middle of rewriting my UIKit app to SwiftUI. Given the requirements, i have to keep root views in UIKit and i'm only allowed to rewrite small pieces/components of the app itself.

I've been rewriting search bar that was initially placed in a navigation bar.
Search bar is now in SwiftUI, however the root controller that is displaying the search bar is still in UIKit (ViewController). I'm using UIHostingController to convert my SwiftUI view into UIKit's type.

`func createSearchBar()`

```
let searchFieldSwiftUI = SearchFieldView(viewModel: viewModel)
let hostingSearchBar = UIHostingController(rootView: searchFieldSwiftUI)
hostingSearchBar.view.backgroundColor = .clear
return hostingSearchBar.view
```

Then in viewDidLoad() i'm setting up my searchBar and i'm assigning it to navigationItem's titleView on the root viewController.

```
let searchBar = createSearchBar()
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

My SearchFieldView is basically a default TextField implementation in SwiftUI:

```
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SearchViewModel
    @FocusState var isSearchBarFocused: Bool
    weak var delegate: AnyObject?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            searchBarStyling(passedView: searchBarView)
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                isSearchBarFocused = true
            }
        }
    }

    private var searchBarView: some View {
        TextField("SEARCH_TEXT".localized, text: $viewModel.updatingText, onEditingChanged: { changed in
            // ... stuff to do onEditingChanged
        }, onCommit: {
            // ... stuff to do onCommit
        })
        .submitLabel(.search)
        .focused($isSearchBarFocused)
    }

    private func searchBarStyling<content: View>(passedView: content) -> some View {
        passedView
            .background(Color(.white))
            .accessibilityElement()
            .accessibilityValue(viewModel.updatingText)
            .overlay(searchBarOverlayView)
            // other attributes
    }
```

There is no way to change @FocusState value that has been attached to TextField programmatically.
Whenever i try changing $isSearchBarFocused in code, it stays on false.

[FocusState stays false after changing it manually in onAppear, asyncAfter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hmij.png)

When i run the app and click on the search bar it works fine, @FocusState is changed, but it looks like it has to be triggered by an user action.

I've tried changing `isSearchBarFocused` value a-synchronically after some specific time (0.5, 1, 1.5 etc.)

Tried changing place of onAppear.

Tried passing down `@FocusState` value from the root viewController. (And changing it's value on viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear using afterAsync in the root VC)

Tried accessing `isSearchBarFocused` wrappedValue and changing it manually.

I'm expecting to change `isSearchBarFocused` value to true onAppear, so that the search bar is focused and keyboard visible whenever i enter that screen.

Unfortunately i can't change the root VC and rewrite it to SwiftUI. I'm thinking this is probably the root cause, but if anyone had experienced something even remotely similar and was able to find a workaround/fix please let me know :)

Comment: Just to clarify this: it seems, your legacy implementation still requires a UIViewController _with an embedded UINavigationController_ as root, and you cannot use a "naked" UIViewController. Is this correct?

Comment: Mostly yeah. I have an UINavigationController that i have to use as root, but i can push whatever i want with it. Right now, i'm creating an instance of the new UIViewController (that holds the SwiftUI views, and where i'm assigning the nav title) and just pushing it on top.

Comment: you cant use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` because Views are value types with no lifetime, you either have to learn async/await and the `.task` modifier or make your own observed object.

Comment: @mahal technically, a copy of the view is made for the closure. I don't like dispatching in a view either, but IMHO it should work, unless making a copy of a view struct has special behaviour and side effects. Nonetheless, it would be worth to try another approach, like `task` modifier or moving the dispatch mechanic into the view's `@ObservedObject`, or just remove the delay completely.

Comment: I'm also concerned with your `weak var delegate: AnyObject?` in the view. Whatever you trying to accomplish, it likely does not work. Note that SwiftUI views are NOT objects. The struct values just exist for the duration of either creating or mutating the underling objects in the system. Please provide a minimal example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper The delegate here shouldn't impact `@FocusState` and TextField being focused programmatically. I am just using it for certain actions.
I've also tried using Enum `FocusedField` with `.focused($focusedField, equals: .searchBar)` on TextField and assigning its value either onAppear or using Task. No luck in both. I believe SwiftUI initially had some issue with Focused, as we had to use DispatchQueue because apparently view wasn't fully "loaded/ready" in .onAppear. So using focused without delaying it wasn't working in some cases.

Comment: What's interesting is that `@FocusState var focusedField: FocusedField?` stays nil even if i assign a value to it.